# Use CloudFlare for reverse proxy?

Tags: apache, nginx, dns, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

I currently am hosting a SPA application via Heroku, and have it linked to my domain:

```
www.mycompany.com
```

This web app serves routes like:

```
www.mycompany.com/about
www.mycompany.com/contact
```

And so on. I'd like to point a subset of this path to a Shopify store:

```
www.mycompany.com/shop
```

So that `/shop` directly shows `mycompany.myshopify.com`, and gracefully handles relative paths after that.

Currently, all my DNS/etc is being handled by CloudFlare.

What is the easiest way to achieve this result?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using cloudflares Route Pattern Matching
https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/api/route-matching/

- Log into your Cloudflare account.
- List item From the dropdown menu on the top left, select your domain.
- Click the Page Rules app in the top menu.
- When adding a new page rule, enable Forwarding.  Basically in the pattern matching you will enter something like - `www.mycompany.com/shop/*`
- Enter the destination URL and select the forwarding type. In your case it will be `mycompany.shopify.com/$1`

That should do the work.

Comment: Isn't this a 301 redirect?

Comment: Any uri (non sub domain) redirect will be a 301. In case of Cloudflare it will be the most fastest because they are handling your DNS too.

Comment: I don't want a redirect. You misunderstood the question.

Comment: If you don’t want redirect than you would require a subdomain e.g. shop.mycompany.com.

Comment: I don't want a subdomain. You misunderstood the question.

Comment: This seems very simple to do? Just add a route for the /shop domain to trigger a worker that simply creates a new Request that actually fetches the shoppify URL? Or am I missing something?